# Parsing Open Weather Map API response fails

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, object

I have this snippet of code:

```
public void getForcast()
{
    string url = string.Format("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22");
    using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
    {
        var json = web.DownloadString(url);
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherData.WeatherForcast>(json);
        WeatherData.WeatherForcast forcast = obj;
        WeatherMark.Text = string.Format("{0}", forcast.list[1].weathers[0].description);
    }
}
```

I want it to get description of it from forecast list.

But instead I'm getting this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

here's my whole list of classes:

```
class WeatherForcast
{
    public List<list> list { get; set; }
}
public class weather
{
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
public class list
{
    public List<weather> weathers { get; set; }
}
```

anyone knows why does it appear?

Comment: The JSON most likely does not match the provided class definition which results in a null object when parsed

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code? What does download json contains? Where exactly do you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON most likely does not match the provided class definition which results in a null object when parsed.

Calling the shown URL in a browser provides the following JSON response

> {"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light
>   intensity
>   drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762037,"sunset":1485794875},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}

Which can be mapped to your shown code already provided with some modification.

```
public class WeatherForcast {
    public List<weather> weather { get; set; }
}

public class weather {
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

There are online tools available where you can place the JSON and it will generate the mapped classes for the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can get weather in Xml using &mode=xml and then use xml serialization :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=xml&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(URL);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Weather));
            Weather weather = (Weather)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("current")]
    public class Weather
    {
        public City city { get; set; }
        public Temperature temperature { get; set; }
        public Humidity humidity { get; set; }
        public Pressure pressure { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
    }
    public class City
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string id { get; set; }

        public Coord coord { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public Sun sun { get; set; }
    }
    public class Sun
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public DateTime rise { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public DateTime set { get; set; }        
    }
    public class Coord
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public decimal lon { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public decimal lat { get; set; }
    }
    public class Temperature
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public decimal value { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public decimal min { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public decimal max { get; set; }
    }
    public class Humidity
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public decimal value { get; set; }
    }
    public class Pressure
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public decimal value { get; set; }
    }
    public class Wind
    {
        public Speed speed { get; set; }
        public Direction direction { get; set; }
    }
    public class Speed
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public decimal value { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Direction
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public decimal value { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string code { get; set; }
    }
}
```